# How to open a model on click of an anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm trying to display a modal on the click of an anchor tag. 
I have dynamically created anchor tags (within a table and divs), on click of which a modal should be displayed...

```
<a href = "#close" class='forum-title' name = "abc">XYZ</a>
```

I've given the "#close" randomly (to prevent it from throwing an error..guessing it's(href) not imp in this case...)

I have given a simple function on the click function of the anchor tag :

```
function openModal() {
            $('#usermodal').modal('show');
              }
```

Please check my **JSFiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/AshleyR098/xaqtawog/623/

UPDATE :

**JSFiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/AshleyR098/xaqtawog/628

-Had given wrong ID to the modal div, tried giving onclick on the anchor tag...Still, no go...

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your function in `window` context and use onclick attribute :

Javascript :

```
function openModal() {
        $('#usermodal').modal('show');
 }
```

HTML:

```
<a href = "#close" class='forum-title' name = "abc" onclick="openModal();">XYZ</a>
```

Comment: Have a look on : http://jsfiddle.net/5ueut7dj/ . The error is now different, but the function is called.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/xaqtawog/637/

```
<a href = "#close" class='forum-title' name = "abc" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#usermodal">XYZ</a>
```

Comment: Great! So there's a bootstrap class for this?!
Thanks!

Comment: @AshleyR. yeah there exist https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-usage

Answer (score 0):

In your JS Fiddler, I saw that you are calling `openDialog` function like this:

```
 $('#<%=abc%>').click(function()
    {
           function openModal() {
             $('#usermodal').modal('show');
            }

    });
```

Can you please remove `openModal` function declaration like this:

```
 $('#<%=abc%>').click(function()
    {
            $('#usermodal').modal('show');

     });
```

Comment: I saw that your model id is `vollist` instead of `usermodal`, means you are using a wrong selector

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do this?

`<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-neutral">Open Modal</a>`